# Change stride of numpy array (altering data)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array and I want to change its `strides` while at the same time modifying its data so that the new array describes the same logical alignment of numbers. Is there any way to do that?

**BACKGROUND**: I read an image file with `cv2.imdecode()`, which produces a BGR image with a lowest-order stride set to 3 (so no gaps between channels of different pixels). I want to modify this image with the `cairo` package, which wants to work with stride 4 (that is, a gap of a byte between two consecutive pixels). Which is the best way to do that? (I would also like to be as optimized as possible, as I have to do this many times).

Comment: So is the input array `(n,m,3)` shape?  And the output `(n,m,4)`?  If so, how about concatenating a `np.zeros((n,m,1))` array?

Comment: Oh yes, that's it. It was trivial, actually, but it didn't come to my mind. Sorry for the noise. If you want to write it as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: I've added an `as_strided` solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the input array is `(n,m,3)`, then it can be expanded to `(n,m,4)` by simply concatenating a `(n,m,1)` array.

```
X = np.ones((n,m,3), dtype='byte')
F = np.zeros((n,m,1), dtype='byte')
X1 = np.concatenate([X,F], axis=2)
```

Strides for these are `(3*m,3,1)`, `(m,1,1)` and `(4*m,4,1)`.

The same data could put in

```
In [72]: dt0 = np.dtype([('R','u1'), ('G','u1'), ('B','u1')])
In [73]: X=np.ones((n,m),dtype=dt0)
In [74]: X.strides
Out[74]: (150, 3)
In [75]: X.shape
Out[75]: (30, 50)
```

With the target having `dt = np.dtype([('R','u1'), ('G','u1'), ('B','u1'), ('A','u1')])`
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html

### Mapping RGB fields to RGBA

But to do concatenation with these dtypes, we'd do some sort of casting to the `(n,m,3)` shape.   Looks like reassigning the `data` attribute will do the trick.

```
n, m = 2, 4
dt1 = np.dtype([('R','u1'), ('G','u1'), ('B','u1'), ('A','u1')])
dt0 = np.dtype([('R','u1'), ('G','u1'), ('B','u1')])
X = np.arange(n*m*3,dtype='u1').reshape(n,m,3)
print repr(X)
X0 = np.zeros((n,m), dtype=dt0)
X0.data = X.data
print repr(X0)
X0.strides # (12, 3)

X1 = np.zeros((n,m), dtype=dt1)
F = np.zeros((n,m,1), dtype='u1')
X01 = np.concatenate([X, F], axis=2)
X1.data = X01.data
print repr(X1)
X1.strides # (12, 4)
```

producing:

```
array([[(0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8), (9, 10, 11)],
       [(12, 13, 14), (15, 16, 17), (18, 19, 20), (21, 22, 23)]], 
      dtype=[('R', 'u1'), ('G', 'u1'), ('B', 'u1')])
array([[(0, 1, 2, 0), (3, 4, 5, 0), (6, 7, 8, 0), (9, 10, 11, 0)],
       [(12, 13, 14, 0), (15, 16, 17, 0), (18, 19, 20, 0), (21, 22, 23, 0)]], 
      dtype=[('R', 'u1'), ('G', 'u1'), ('B', 'u1'), ('A', 'u1')])
```

### Using overlapping dtypes

Here's a way of doing it with overlapping dtypes rather than concatenation:

```
dt0 = np.dtype([('R','u1'), ('G','u1'), ('B','u1')])
dt1 = np.dtype([('R','u1'), ('G','u1'), ('B','u1'), ('A','u1')])
dtb = np.dtype({'names':['rgb','rgba'],
                'offsets':[0,0],
                'formats':[dt0, dt1]})
X0 = np.zeros((n,m), dtype=dt0)
X0.data = X.data
X1 = np.zeros((n,m), dtype=dtb)
X1['rgb'][:] = X0
print repr(X1['rgba'])
```

Or without the individual named byte fields it's even simpler:

```
dt0 = np.dtype(('u1',(3,)))
dt1 = np.dtype(('u1',(4,)))
dtb = np.dtype({'names':['rgb','rgba'],
                'offsets':[0,0],
                'formats':[dt0, dt1]})
X = np.arange(n*m*3,dtype='u1').reshape(n,m,3)
X1 = np.zeros((n,m), dtype=dtb)
X1['rgb'][:] = X
```

`X1['rgba']` is `(n,m,4)`, with strides `(m*4, 4, 1)`.

`X1['rgb']` is `(n,m,3)`, but with the same strides `(m*4, 4, 1)`.

### Using `as_strided`

That difference in shape, but similarity in strides, suggest's using `as_strided`.  Create the empty target array, and use `as_strided` to select a subset of elements to receive values from `X`:

```
X1 = np.zeros((n,m,4),dtype='u1')
np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(X1, shape=X.shape, strides=X1.strides)[:] = X
print X1
```